# Unity3d ARKit not reset

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using vuforia & ARKit sdk in my application.
I have two buttons ( Vuforia & ARKit buttons)
My app work flow:

1. Open the app
2. Clicked on “vuforia AR” button (1st time)
3. If marker found Vuforia AR works.
4. i am switch to “ARKit” 1st time, it will be working fine.
5. If we press back button, it will redirect to MainScreen
6. Again Click on “vuforia AR” button (2nd time)
7. Vuforia working good.
8. If we switch to “ARKit” , ARKit Camera is not resetting .

Here arkit camera is freezing.

Note: both SDK are using single scene and I tried two different scenes also. My issue is not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you solved your problem.
If not, did you tried to reset your ARKit scene ?
Here's a sample code I founded in another post. Working fine for me to reset my ARKit Session.

```
   public void ResetScene()
    {
        ARKitWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration sessionConfig = new ARKitWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration(UnityARAlignment.UnityARAlignmentGravity, UnityARPlaneDetection.Horizontal);
        UnityARSessionNativeInterface.GetARSessionNativeInterface().RunWithConfigAndOptions(sessionConfig, UnityARSessionRunOption.ARSessionRunOptionRemoveExistingAnchors | UnityARSessionRunOption.ARSessionRunOptionResetTracking);
    }
```

Don't forget to change sessionConfig parameters with yours ! ;)